# Merge PDFs in Ghostscript with Python list of UNC Paths

Tags: python, python-3.7

I am trying to build a multipage PDF using Ghostscript by combining a list of single-page PDFs from their UNC file-paths (working in Python 3.7).
Here is the function:

```
import subprocess
import os

def ghostscript_merge_pdfs(in_PDF_list, out_PDF):
    """some doc string"""
    # pdfPathsAsStr = '"' + ' "'.join(f'{pdf}"' for pdf in in_PDF_list)
    pdfPathsAsStr = ' '.join(pdf for pdf in in_PDF_list)

    print("The 'pdfPathsAsStr' variable is:")
    print(pdfPathsAsStr + "\n")

    args = [r"\\someDir\subDir\T\Tools\Ghostscript_Tools\GS_Install\gs9.54.0\bin\gswin64c",
            '-sDEVICE=pdfwrite',
            '-dNOPAUSE',
            "-sOUTPUTFILE=" + out_PDF,
            pdfPathsAsStr
            ]

    p = subprocess.Popen(args, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    print("\nCompleted: \n" + str(p.communicate()))

pdf_dir = r"\\someDir\subDir\T\Tools\Ghostscript_Tools\GS_Testing\IndividualPages"
out_pdf_path = os.path.join(pdf_dir, "Combo_PDF.pdf")

pdfs_list = [os.path.join(pdf_dir, "PDF_1.pdf"), os.path.join(pdf_dir, "PDF_2.pdf")]

ghostscript_merge_pdfs(pdfs_list, out_pdf_path)
```

The script outputs the following (note that slashes in `pdfPathsAsStr` are not quadruplicated):

```
The 'pdfPathsAsStr' variable is:
\\someDir\subDir\T\Tools\Ghostscript_Tools\GS_Testing\IndividualPages\PDF_1.pdf \\someDir\subDir\T\Tools\Ghostscript_Tools\GS_Testing\IndividualPages\PDF_2.pdf


Completed: 
(b'GPL Ghostscript 9.54.0 (2021-03-30)\nCopyright (C) 2021 Artifex Software, Inc.  All rights reserved.\nThis software is supplied under the GNU AGPLv3 and comes with NO WARRANTY:\nsee the file COPYING for details.\nError: /undefinedfilename in (\\\\\\\\someDir\\\\subDir\\\\T\\\\Tools\\\\Ghostscript_Tools\\\\GS_Testing\\\\IndividualPages\\\\PDF_1.pdf \\\\\\\\someDir\\\\subDir\\\\T\\\\Tools\\\\Ghostscript_Tools\\\\GS_Testing\\\\IndividualPages\\\\PDF_2.pdf)\nOperand stack:\n\nExecution stack:\n   %interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   false   1   %stopped_push\nDictionary stack:\n   --dict:732/1123(ro)(G)--   --dict:0/20(G)--   --dict:75/200(L)--\nCurrent allocation mode is local\nLast OS error: No such file or directory\n', None)

GPL Ghostscript 9.54.0: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1
```

I have looked a few places for help with UNC paths in Ghostscript, but can't find much help. I have tried a few variations of `pdfPathsAsStr` inside the function, with no luck.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Look at the Ghostscript error message; undefined filename in (\\\\\\\\someDir\\\\subDir....).  Somewhere in there you are apparently quadrupling the backslashes, you need to find out where that is happening. The most likely culprit to me looks like os.path.join but really, you should just print out the string at each step to find out. This isn't a PostScript or Ghostscript question.

Comment: Thanks @KenS, to be sure, should network file paths be passed, for example, as "\\someDir\subDir\T\Tools\Ghostscript_Tools\GS_Testing\IndividualPages\PDF_1.pdf"?

Comment: I added a few print statements, and included their output above. @KenS, are you sure this isn't a Ghostscript problem? Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes I'm sure, Ghostscript won't add to the path it's supplied with. If it says you've got multiple backslashes in there, then I'd believe it. As K J says below, I always use forward slashes on Windows with Ghostscript; it's entirely happy with '/' as a path separator, it works on the majority of platforms and avoids confusion with escapes. As regards network paths, well GS just uses the win32 API so if your network path works with Windows it should be OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following command **outside python** runs for me no problem.

```
gswin64c -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -o"\\advent\share\Merged.pdf" "\\advent\share\cover.pdf" "\\advent\share\PDF files in a folder.pdf"
```

Showing that remote windows folders are not a problem for Ghostscript input or output.

Your problem is the way python handles windows pathing, and that can be minimised by reversing the folder names so that only the server name needs a \\prefix in windows.

```
gswin64c -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -o"\\advent/share/Merged.pdf" "\\advent/share/cover.pdf" "\\advent/share/PDF files in a folder.pdf"
```

So in python use `\\\\` for server prefix when needed but use / in paths to make life easier (yes I know its not best practice, but life is short and its less rsi from the keyboard).

to test what cmd is getting from python just run `cmd /k echo "\\\\blah/blah"` as your executable command